Webdriver BiDi listeners, getting bodies of request and response
Hi I am trying to replace devtools with BiDi in my project. Can I get request and response bodies from BeforeRequestSent and ResponseDetails? any form like json or byte sequence or string would be great.
like this for example:
network.onBeforeRequestSent(request -> {           
    System.out.println(request.getBody());
    System.out.println(request.getRequest().getRequestBody());
    System.out.println(network.getRequestBody(request.getRequest().getRequestId()));
});


Based on the BiDi documentation, there is no such option. Which is very strange, because at the network.beforeRequestSent stage it is possible to change the request body content, but it is inconvenient without knowing the original request body.
Tried to search for solutions, couldn't find anything. Checking for updates on this. If you have found something working, I would be grateful if you could share it

This is an "I'm having this problem too" comment rather than an answer.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
